# "list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando desenvolver um jogo da velha em python, que recebe um usuário que jogará contra o computador, a saída deve dizer o vencedor do jogo ou se deu velha. Quase tudo está correto, com exceção de quando o jogo dá velha, pois recebo o seguinte erro:

> File "C:\Users\Pedroh\Desktop\jogo da velha do 0.py", line 244, in 
>       defineJogada(tabuleiro, computadorlet, jogada)
>     File "C:\Users\Pedroh\Desktop\jogo da velha do 0.py", line 99, in
>    defineJogada
>       espaco[jogada] = letra
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Este é o meu código:

```
import random
import sys
import time

Computador = str('Computador')

def sorteioPrimeiraJogada(lista):
    sorteio=random.choice(lista)
    return sorteio




def desenhoDoTabuleiro(espaco):    
    print('      |      |')
    print('   ' + str(espaco[0]) + '  |   ' + str(espaco[1]) + '  | ' + str(espaco[2]))
    print('      |      |')
    print('--------------------')
    print('      |      |')
    print('   ' + str(espaco[10]) + '  |   ' + str(espaco[11]) + '  | ' + str(espaco[12]))
    print('      |      |')
    print('--------------------')
    print('      |      |')
    print('   ' + str(espaco[20]) + '  |   ' + str(espaco[21]) + '  | ' + str(espaco[22]))
    print('      |      |')

def posicaoTabuleiro():

    print('      |      |')
    print('  ' '00' '  |  ''01' '  | ' '02')
    print('      |      |')
    print('--------------------')
    print('      |      |')
    print('  ' '10' '  |  ''11' '  | ' '12')
    print('      |      |')
    print('--------------------')
    print('      |      |')
    print('  ' '20' '  |  ''21' '  | ' '22')
    print('      |      |')
    print(' ')
    print(' ')


def solicitaSimboloDoHumano ():
    while True:
        variavel=str(input('Com qual símbolo você prefere jogar(X ou O)? ')).upper()
        if variavel== 'X' or variavel=='x' :
            print('Você jogará contra o computador, que usará O.')
            break
        elif variavel== 'O' or variavel=='o':
            print('Você jogará contra o computador, que usará X.')
            break
        else:        
            print('Você não digitou um símbolo válido.')
    return variavel

def listaLetra():
    global variavel
    if variavel== 'X' or variavel=='x':
        letra = ['X','O']
    elif variavel== 'O' or variavel=='o' or variavel=='0':
        letra= ['O','X']
    return letra

def jogarNovamente():
    print('Você quer jogar novamente?(sim ou não)')
    jn=input().lower().startswith('s')
    while not jn:            
            print('Volte Sempre!')
            time.sleep(2)
            sys.exit()      

            return False
    return True    


def defineJogada(espaco, letra, jogada):
    espaco[jogada] = letra



def verificaVencedor(ep, var):

    return ((ep[0] == var and ep[1] == var and ep[2] == var) or 
    (ep[10] == var and ep[11] == var and ep[12] == var) or 
    (ep[20] == var and ep[21] == var and ep[22] == var) or 
    (ep[0] == var and ep[10] == var and ep[20] == var) or 
    (ep[1] == var and ep[11] == var and ep[21] == var) or 
    (ep[2] == var and ep[12] == var and ep[22] == var) or 
    (ep[0] == var and ep[11] == var and ep[22] == var) or 
    (ep[2] == var and ep[11] == var and ep[20] == var))



def copiaTabuleiro(espaco):

    copiaespaco = []

    for i in espaco:
        copiaespaco.append(i)

    return copiaespaco


def temEspacoLivre(espaco,jogada):  
    return espaco[jogada] == ' '



def jogadaHumana():
    print('Qual a sua jogada? (x e y[0,2])')
    jogada=input()
    return jogada



def validaJogada(espaco):

    global jogada
    while jogada not in '00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22'.split() or not temEspacoLivre(espaco,int(jogada)):

        print('Você não digitou uma jogada válida.')
        jogada = jogadaHumana()
    return int(jogada)

def escolheJogadaAleatoriaDaLista(espaco, listaDeJogadas):

    jogadasPossiveis = []
    for i in listaDeJogadas:
        if temEspacoLivre(espaco, i):
            jogadasPossiveis.append(i)

    if len(jogadasPossiveis) != 0:
        return random.choice(jogadasPossiveis)
    else:
        return None

def jogadaComputador(espaco, computadorlet):

    if computadorlet == 'X':
        jogadorlet = 'O'
    else:
        jogadorlet = 'X'


    for i in range(0, 23):
        copia = copiaTabuleiro(espaco)
        if temEspacoLivre(copia, i):
            defineJogada(copia, computadorlet, i)
            if verificaVencedor(copia, computadorlet):
                return i


    for i in range(0, 23):
        copia = copiaTabuleiro(espaco)
        if temEspacoLivre(copia, i):
            defineJogada(copia, jogadorlet, i)
            if verificaVencedor(copia, jogadorlet):
                return i


    jogada = escolheJogadaAleatoriaDaLista(espaco, [0, 2, 20, 22])
    if jogada != None:
        return jogada


    if temEspacoLivre(espaco, 11):
        return 11


    return escolheJogadaAleatoriaDaLista(espaco, [21, 10, 12, 1])


def verificaVelha(espaco):

    for i in range(0, 23):
        if temEspacoLivre(espaco, i):
            return False

    return True


while True:
    tabuleiro = [' ']*23

    nome_ok = False
    while nome_ok == False:        
            nome=input('Qual é o seu nome(ou apelido)? ')
            if nome:
                nome_ok = True


    lista = [nome, Computador]
    variavel = solicitaSimboloDoHumano()
    jogadorlet, computadorlet = listaLetra()
    vez = sorteioPrimeiraJogada(lista)
    print ('A partida começará por %s.' %vez)
    jogoAcontecendo = True
    while jogoAcontecendo:
        if vez == nome:
            posicaoTabuleiro()
            desenhoDoTabuleiro(tabuleiro)
            jogada = jogadaHumana()
            movimento = validaJogada(tabuleiro)
            defineJogada(tabuleiro,jogadorlet,movimento)
            if verificaVencedor(tabuleiro, jogadorlet):
                posicaoTabuleiro()
                desenhoDoTabuleiro(tabuleiro)
                print('Vencedor: %s' %nome)
                jogoAcontecendo = False
            else:
                if verificaVelha(tabuleiro):

                    desenhoDoTabuleiro(tabuleiro)
                    print('Deu velha!')
                    break
                else:
                    vez = Computador

        else:

            jogada = jogadaComputador(tabuleiro, computadorlet)
            defineJogada(tabuleiro, computadorlet, jogada)

            if verificaVencedor(tabuleiro, computadorlet):
                posicaoTabuleiro()
                desenhoDoTabuleiro(tabuleiro)
                print('Vencedor: Computador')
                jogoAcontecendo = False
            else:
                if verificaVelha(tabuleiro):

                    desenhoDoTabuleiro(tabuleiro)
                    print('Deu velha!')
                    break
                else:
                    vez = nome

    if not jogarNovamente():
        break
```

Gostaria que alguém me esclarecesse que erro estou recebendo, e como posso consertá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro que você tem é bem clara: ao tentar acessar a lista
`espaco`, a variável `jogada` que você usa como índice contém `None` em vez de um inteiro.

Então é só acompanhar onde você chama essa função, e vai descobrir que na jogada do computador, as vezes você vai pegar o retorno desta função:

```
def escolheJogadaAleatoriaDaLista(espaco, listaDeJogadas):

    jogadasPossiveis = []
    for i in listaDeJogadas:
        if temEspacoLivre(espaco, i):
            jogadasPossiveis.append(i)

    if len(jogadasPossiveis) != 0:
        return random.choice(jogadasPossiveis)
    else:
        return None
```

E olha aí - tem uma condição em que ela retorna `None`. Isso causa o seu erro. (Se o tabuleiro não estiver cheio ainda, pode haver também um erro na sua "jogadas possíveis").

Parabéns pelo projeto. Você poderia usar um dicionário em vez de uma lista, e manter o esquema de coordenadas fixas que está usando - mas aí não terá posições em branco na sua variável "espaco" que não tem nada a ver com o jogo.

Comment: Bom dia jsbueno, o que você me recomentaria para preencher o retorno da função com algo que tenha o mesmo ofício do None? Porque é necessário o retorno None para verificar se o tabuleiro está cheio, como bem deve entender..